# PHP 5.3 Upgrade - Can't Connect to MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql

I've done a bit of research on this today, but nothing seems to address this issue.  I recently upgraded to PHP 5.3.3 from 5.1.6, as well as upgraded MySQL to 5.5 from 5.0.  Afterwards, the following code generates an error saying "Can't connect to mysql database":

```
$connection =  mysql_pconnect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
if (!$connection) {
  //Can't connect
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  return;
}
```

And get the following error:

> Warning: mysql_pconnect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on '199.59.157.103' (13) in /var/www/html/ws/Cust/customerWS_1_1.php on line 19 Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '199.59.157.103' (13)

I am able to connect to the remote host via the command line, and have tried everything from resetting the password to shutting down IP Tables.  I'm kind of at a loss - so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem with the same error message "*Can't connect to mysql database*" and maybe the following points will be also usefull:

- check mysql user privileges (in our case and with external connections we had the old server IP address (allow access) in the table)  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tablename.* TO 'username'@'145.1.1.2';`
  -> reload privileges after changes (`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`)
- disable the SELinux parameter. In new Plesk versions (>10?) this would be set enabled automatically...
  --> in /etc/selinux/config change the line that says:

  `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=disabled`
   See further details: http://googolflex.com/?p=482

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP 5.3 mysql driver restriction related to old authentication scheme hash stored in the database by previous mysql server. This could cause a problem with stored passwords so the databases will be unaccessible with old passwords.

To solve the problem you should recreate the mysql users with the same login and same password.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I am able to connect to the remote host via the command line" do you mean, you are connecting to the MySQL server REMOTELY? Or that you are SSHing to your MySQL server and connecting to it from the MySQL server's command line? If the latter, it's possible that when you upgraded to MySQL 5.5 you accidentally stopped MySQL from binding / listening on a public IP.  Check your `my.cnf`.

Otherwise: is your PHP code being run on the same server as your MySQL server?  It's possible that your permissions could be off.  MySQL permissions are very particular about connecting to the MySQL server via it's IP address if the client only has access to connect from 'localhost', and vice-versa.

Comment: When I say remote connection - I mean that from the server hosting my web content I can connect using mysql -h <remote_host_ip>.  If it were an issue with MySQL not listening correctly, it shouldn't allow any remote connections at all, right?

Comment: Correct.  When you're connecting from the command line are you using the same username and password your script is attempting to use?

Comment: Yes.  Even if I hard-code the connection info I still receive the same error.  Checking mundane things like that is usually the first thing I do before I facepalm :)

Comment: just as a test...what if you `mysql_connect` instead of `mysql_pconnect`?

Comment: ): Do you have another MySQL server you can test?  That's an obscenely weird issue.

Comment: I do actually.  When I point the page to a different server that I know is working I get the same connection error, which leads me to believe this could be related to a php configuration issue?  Additionally, if I point the code from our old server (php 5.1) to the new db server (mysql 5.5) I don't get the connection error.  It seems to be a problem with the server running php 5.3.

Comment: At least you know where to look now...see if you can find anything in your error logs concerning the MySQL PHP library.  You can also try doing `php -r 'echo "foo";'` on the command line, see if you get any php errors output to STDOUT concerning the MySQL PHP lib.

Comment: This is what I get: [root@carlwww1 conf.d]# php -r '
$connect = mysql_pconnect("199.59.157.103", "name", "password");
> var_dump($connect);
> '
resource(4) of type (mysql link persistent)
... So i'm pretty stumped.  It looks like it is connecting just fine, except when that's in a .php file...

Comment: @tdk2fe - `php -i | grep php.ini` on the command line, and `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and load that from your browser. are they loading the same `php.ini`s?

Comment: They appear to be using the same .ini file.  However, one thing I did notice was that the client version on the web server is 5.0.77, while mysql running on the database server is 5.5.10.  Would this be an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that it would, especially with the cli execution of the mysql connection running but not the apache script version...

Comment: Well still no luck - i'll poke around this weekend and hopefully find a solution!

Comment: Hey Jim - finally found out what was causing it (although a bit delayed in my response here!)  I disabled SELinux running on the web server that was trying to connect to the MySql server.  Its a development environment on an internal network, so I'm not worried about it ATM.  Once it was disabled, the connection was established just fine.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SELinux, but I guess you're "supposed" to create a rule to let mysql traffic through. Or, disable it (:

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that the connect parameters `$dbhost`, `$dbusername` and `$dbpassword` are correct. Assuming these are correct, you should check your mysql ini settings. I would assume that the bind-address is set to 127.0.0.1 or localhost, but not to a public IP address.

Also note that it's a security risk if you can connect to mysql from a public IP address. You may want to look into a solution that does not require such connection.